# D3: axis incorrectly rendering when setting ticks()

Tags: javascript, d3.js

*EDIT: rewrote the question to be more precise and relevant*

I understand that the number of ticks should be dependent on the type of scale one uses and show the most intelligently spaced and formatted human-readable values as possible, given the input domain.

I am trying to track down the change that broke my original implementation. The major change is upgrading my d3 to v3.4.8, although I encounter the same problem when using jsfiddle.com's d3 v3.0.4 in my code.

I set it up the axis like this:

```
    var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, 880])
        .range([0, 275]);  // the width in pixels of the axis

    var d3Axis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(xScale)
        .orient('bottom')
        .tickSize(5, 3, 0)  // major, minor, end
        .tickPadding(4)
        .ticks(5);

    // render
    var d3AxisNode = someParentNode
        .append('g')
        .call(d3Axis);
```

This is my pre-v3.4.8 axis with these settings:

[image: How it should look]

Here is what it looks like now:

[image: How it looks now]

This it how it looks when I don't set ticks at all (default = 10):

[image: Not setting ticks]

There is probably something in my code out-with the pasted stuff here that is causing the problem, but there are no errors and all code completes fine. Since I don't load any other JS libraries and have even stripped everything down to just rendering a test axis with minimal scaffolding, I am interested if someone recognises this as a result of an obvious flaw when working with D3 axes, to help me hunt the root cause (I have been hunting too long already).

Has anyone else experienced this type of problem? Any thoughts are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: From the [API docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#linear_ticks) "The specified count is only a hint; the scale may return more or fewer values depending on the input domain."

Comment: I use this method with no issues. Perhaps post the code sample in question.

Comment: @Martin yes, I know that but it seems to not even come close to my number, whereas before 3.4.6 it did. Also, precisely because of the fuzziness of this "hint", I am asking whether this feature is even useful.

Comment: @explunit which version of D3 are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 3.4.8

Comment: Can you post a specific example.  I suspect there is another problem going on -- perhaps your number formatting is off, and you're getting NaN values.  Using the latest stable version of d3 (JSFiddle just links to d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js, currently that's 3.4.8), I get ticks at [0,200,400,600,800] when I ask for 4 ticks in the domain [0,880]: http://fiddle.jshell.net/zUj3E/32/

Comment: @AmeliaBR you are correct, I think there is something else going on; it must have happened in an unexpected place while refactoring. I found out when I copied the new version of D3 along with the affected files into the working branch -- all good. Now I just need to keep at it. Sorry for the misleading title in the question, the nature of the problem has changed ... There's way too much code over many files to post here I'm afraid. Thank you for your comment!

Comment: @chrisn If you can narrow down the problem, please edit the question to be relevant, otherwise you might want to close since this is unlikely to help other people searching for information on d3 ticks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out that, like many things in life, ["turning it off and on again"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p85xwZ_OLX0) seems to have the trick this time around.

I shut down the server, cleaned the JS assets, cleared the browser cache, then ran the app afresh and lo, my axes worked again.

To anyone experiencing weird behaviour in a complex stack that doesn't seem logical and fails to turn up useful help when googled, it's probably best to just hit the switch twice.